# Vlookup multiple values from a cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

I have two tables

```
Table A
ID      
----------
foo
baz, bar
foo,abc,bar
ham
egg
```

```
Table B
ID
---------
foo
baz
bar
abc
ham
burger
abc
```

I want to create `column B` in `Table A`. It must look up the values in `Column A` in Table B's `Column A`. With multiple values like `baz, bar`, both the values must be looked up, and if found the results must be stored.
How should go for this?

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),H:H,1,FALSE)).
```

It outputs

```
foo
baz
foo
ham
#N/A
```

Desired Output:

```
foo 
baz, bar 
foo,abc,bar 
ham 
#N/A
```

Comment: Multiple lookup results in a single cell: you will need VBA for that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help you with errors in your current code. There are tons of approach to your question that you can find in this very same site. Please edit your question and add your code to help you out.

Comment: @Damian I am really clueless which approach should I take.

Comment: @Variatus, or have access to `TEXTJOIN` (which isn't available in Excel 2016).

Comment: @JvdV I am having TEXTJOIN in my Excel

Comment: Also, if not Excel 2016, then what version do you have?

Comment: @JvdV Excel for MS365

Comment: So please include your own attempt and desired result

Comment: @JvdV ```=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),H:H,1,FALSE))```. It outputs ```foo, baz, foo, ham,#N/A```. But, I am looking for is ```foo
baz, bar
foo,abc,bar
ham
#N/A```

Comment: @HimeshRana, best to update your question for clarity. But you are on the right track. Filterxml and Textjoin is a great combo for this =)

Comment: @JvdV Yeah, I have done that. Can you look at it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),B$1:B$7,B$1:B$7,,0))
```

If you don't want `#N/A` then use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,XLOOKUP(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),B$1:B$7,B$1:B$7,"",0))
```

Comment: Then use `VLOOKUP`: `=TEXTJOIN(",",,VLOOKUP(TRIM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),B$1:B$7,1,0))`

Comment: In the case of ```XYZ, foo```, it will output ```foo```. It must output ```foo``` but it is outputting ```#N/A```. Also, I am getting a single output like previously
(in my question).

Comment: You probably do not have Excel O365 at all, but Excel 2019 (which does have `TEXTJOIN()` available). But in that case just make sure accept the formula through Ctrl+Shift+Enter. @HimeshRana

Comment: @HimeshRana, has this question been answered? If so, don't forget to accept the answer.